# How to decrease the slider speed

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

I want to decrease the slider speed in Bootstrap, while changing one slide to another slide. And I want to decrease the time of animation while changing  slide.

```
 <section id="slide-show" style='display: <%= SiteMap.RootNode.Url!=SiteMap.CurrentNode.Url?"none":"block" %>'>
        <div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">

            <!--Slider Items-->
            <div class="sl-slider">
                <!--Slider Item1-->
                <div class="sl-slide item1" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                    <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                        <div class="container">
                            <img class="pull-right" src="themes/images/bdev.png" alt="" />
                            <h2>Time-to-fill</h2>

                            <h3 class="gap">Benefit from our services include short recruitment cycle for a
  quicker "Time-to-fill". </h3>
                            <%--                                <a class="btn btn-large btn-transparent" href="#">Learn More</a>--%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following script in your HTML. 1000 equal to 1 second.

```
 <script>
  $('.sl-slider').carousel({
  interval: 10000
   });
</script>
```

Refer http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel for more information.

Comment: i have an effect in slider , while changing one slide to another change , one effect is there vertical and horizontal disappering. how to slow down that effect ? @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: what is the type of script ? is it  <script type="text/javascript"> ? @Suresh